# Vba Selenium problems

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had this pop out box stated with "no such element error". I really don't know what's wrong with the code. This basic code is actually looking up for the search box and input text which is ABC. I hope I can find someone who can kindly guide me. Your help will be very much appreciated. TQ

Sub AlwayUseTheToTest()
'
' AlwayUseTheToTest Macro
'

'
Dim mybrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver

```
Set mybrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

sel.Start "chrome", "https://www.carousell.sg"
sel.Get "/"
'Stop

sel.FindElementByCss("a.D_pG.D_pH.D_pT.D_mz").SendKeys "ABC"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

***NoSuchElementException*** is one of the different WebDriver Exceptions and this Exception occurs, when the locators `(i.e. id / xpath/ css selectors etc)` we mentioned in the Selenium Program code is unable to find the web element on the web page. There are two possibilities for getting this Exception, i.e. either we have provided a incorrect locator and trying to find the web element or we have provided correct locator, but the `web element` related to the locator is not *available* on the web page.

Please try using the below

***XPATH***

```
//input[@placeholder='Search for an item']
```

***CSS SELECTOR***

```
input[placeholder='Search for an item']
```

***Note***: Put some `waits` while locating to the element, as I do not know in `Vba`, but in  `java` like below

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
WebElement  elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for an item']")));
elem.sendKeys("ABC");
```

*Hope this answer your question*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response to my problem, But I am really sorry, I don't really understand how to go about with the information provided. Do you mind, can help me in completing the code with or help me to fill up the blank?

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
WebElement  elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search for an item']")));
elem.sendKeys("ABC");